# how to use Qt open ROS package?

Tags: c++, bash, qt, ros

I want to use qt to open my ROS packages which can be compiled by "catkin_make" in terminal(QT 5.8 ubuntu 16.04 ROS kinetic). [qt cannot open it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uwtoz.png)
And I fixed "~/.local/share/applications/DigiaQt-qtcreator-community.desktop", added "bash -i -c"But it still does not work. [fix qt desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GR07.png)
Besides, I also tryed to fix .bashrc 
"alias qt='bash -c /home/cgd/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator'" and it also failed.
so, what should I do? please help me!  thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=bash -i -c /opt/Qt5.6.2/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator
Name=Qt Creator (Community)
GenericName=The IDE of choice for Qt development.
Icon=QtProject-qtcreator
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Qt;
MimeType=text/x-c++src;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-xsrc;application/x-designer;application/vnd.qt.qmakeprofile;application/vnd.qt.xml.resource;text/x-qml;text/x-qt.qml;text/x-qt.qbs;
```

This is my qt.desktop .Add try open a basic package not total package to see it works or not . Just open the CMakeLists.txt under the package.

Comment: I reinstall the offline version of the qt 5.6, taking the above your operation and it works! online-install 5.8 version is still not OK...Thank you very much 
for your reply to my question!